# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument for read() in Python

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I am using Python to read a large file in macOS 10.13. It seems that everytime I try to read a large file it just simply fails. Code:

```
f = open('file_name', 'r')

x = f.read()

print(x)
```

The scripts work well when the file `file_name` is small, but fails when reading large files (in my case, 3.5GB):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/mengzhao/PycharmProjects/testread/readthisfile.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mengzhao/PycharmProjects/testread/readthisfile.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = f.read()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have 16GB memory and I am sure it is not because of the memory. And `sys.version` gives me this:

```
3.6.1 (default, Apr  4 2017, 09:40:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)]
```

And it does not matter whether I use 'rb' or 'r', I just have the same problem. Here are some debug information after the first line is executed. It seems that the `open` method is fine:

[image]

Besides, I changed to `python 2.7.10` and the code works. It seems that the problem has something to do with `Python3` on Mac. Both `Python 3.5.2` and `Python 3.6.1` does not work.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What does `import sys; print(sys.version)` give you?

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: Also, what **exactly** are you passing to `f = open('file_name', 'r')` when it fails?

Comment: There's a million "OSError: [Errno 22] when I try to .read()" questions on SO already.  What makes this one unique?  Without exact repro steps and data, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga gives me this:  3.6.1 (default, Apr  4 2017, 09:40:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)]

Comment: @user2357112 I have 16GB of memory

Comment: @I am passing a 3.58GB file to open. From debug information, it seems that the open method works just as fine.

Comment: @Ssswift sorry for confusing. I have added more information.

Comment: Acctually X_train.npy is the training set of a Kaggle project. The same scripts works well on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: are you using 32bit versions of Python?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am sure it is a 64bit version

Comment: >>> import platform
>>> print(platform.architecture())
('64bit', '')

Comment: I am running into the same error (3.6GB file) inside a Jupyter notebook. When I execute the file.read() in the python shell, the read operation is successful.

Comment: Having the exact same issue.