# "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" when read()ing a huge file

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, file-io

I'm trying to write a small script that prints the checksum of a file (using some code from https://gist.github.com/Zireael-N/ed36997fd1a967d78cb2):

```
import sys
import os
import hashlib

file = '/Users/Me/Downloads/2017-11-29-raspbian-stretch.img'

with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print('SHA256 of file is %s' % hashlib.sha256(contents).hexdigest())
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checksum.py", line 8, in <module>
    contents = f.read()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using python 3 on macOS High Sierra

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Does this happen when trying to take the checksum of any file or only a specific file?  Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  Why does your error message say `contents = f.read()` is line 8 when it's only line 6 of the code given here?

Comment: Have you tried other files? Python simply translates error code it got from operating system (`EINVAL`) and there is a chance that error code comes from filesystem driver itself (so it can be bug in it). Normally `EINVAL` in response to read means that fd number is wrong but it is unususal situation as Python controls correctness of fd number on itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSError \[Errno 22\] invalid argument when use open() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584124/oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-when-use-open-in-python)

Comment: @roganjosh: The answers given there only apply to Windows systems.  This question appears to be about a problem on macOS.

Comment: I tried other files now, and they worked fine. The original .img file still gives the same error message though. Could it be because of it's size of 4,92 GB?

Comment: @Hallvard: What version of Python are you on? And are you on a 32 bit system? There are a couple issues that could arise depending on the answers to those two questions.

Comment: @roganjosh: It's not a duplicate of that one. That one is an error on `open` (bad file path), for this question the `open` succeeded, but the `read` failed. The causes of one are unlikely to relate to the other.

Comment: Why not just use `sha256sum`

Comment: Regardless, it's silly to read the whole multi-GB file into memory at once -- there's no need to do that; you can hash it a piece at a time.

Comment: I'm using Python version 3.6.2, and the system is 64 bit (MacBook Air).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46458537/364696) appears to be an exact duplicate, but it's also unanswered. I'm guessing some bug in how Python is invoking a Mac system call that works correctly on all other POSIX systems, but I lack a Mac to test, and searches on the Python bug tracker are coming up empty.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There [have been](https://bugs.python.org/issue15896) [several](https://bugs.python.org/issue21932) [issues](https://bugs.python.org/issue25626) over the history of Python (most fixed in recent versions) reading more than 2-4 GB at once from a file handle (an unfixable version of the problem also occurs on 32 bit builds of Python, where they simply lack the virtual address space to allocate the buffer; not I/O related, but seen most frequently slurping large files). A workaround available for hashing is to update the hash in fixed size chunks (which is a good idea anyway, since counting on RAM being greater than file size is a poor idea). The most straightforward approach is to change your code to:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()  # Make empty hasher to update piecemeal
    while True:
        block = f.read(64 * (1 << 20)) # Read 64 MB at a time; big, but not memory busting
        if not block:  # Reached EOF
            break
        hasher.update(block)  # Update with new block
print('SHA256 of file is %s' % hasher.hexdigest())  # Finalize to compute digest
```

If you're feeling fancy, you can "simplify" the loop using two-arg `iter` and some `functools` magic, replacing the whole of the `while` loop with:

```
for block in iter(functools.partial(f.read, 64 * (1 << 20)), b''):
    hasher.update(block)
```

Or on Python 3.8+, with [the walrus operator, `:=`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) it's simpler without the need for imports or unreadable code:

```
while block := f.read(64 * (1 << 20)):  # Assigns and tests result in conditional!
    hasher.update(block)
```

Comment: Wow, that was perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score -4):

Wow this can be much simpler. Just read the file line by line:

```
with open('big-file.txt') as f:
  for i in f:
    print(i)
```